# Writing to Excel, using panda drop

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am writing a script that will write to an Excel spreadsheet.  The original xlsx file has one worksheet with all of the columns.  I would like to create separate worksheets, each with a subset of the columns.  So far, I have gotten the create_sheet and sheet_names to work correctly.  The issue is with the column drop coding.  When I run the script the print indicates the correct number of output columns as well as the columns that should be included, but when I open the xlsx file, all of the columns are still there.  IS there something more I need to do to get those columns removed (dropped)?

### Here is the code:

```
#Filter xls and create worksheets

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import os
print ("importing modules")

print ("copy data")

wb1 = load_workbook(filename=readFileName)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[1]

wb2 = load_workbook(filename=writer)
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

wb2.save(writer)
print ("copied sheet2")
                    
  for t in range(len(wb2.sheetnames)):
    if wb2.sheetnames[t] == 'level1':
        break
wb2.active = t
print(t)

source_df = pd.read_excel(writer, t)

print(source_df)
result_df = source_df.drop(['ObjectID', 'GlobalID', 'WSSN.1', 'The Quarter you are Submitting for Review'], axis=1)

for u in range(len(wb2.sheetnames)):
    if wb2.sheetnames[u] == 'treatment':
        break
wb2.active = u
print(u)
print(result_df)
source_df2 = pd.read_excel(writer, u)

print(source_df2)
result_df2 = source_df2.drop(['ObjectID', 'GlobalID', 'WSSN.1', 'The Quarter you are 
Submitting for Review', 'Enter in which Fiscal Year you are submitting for review:'], axis=1)

print(result_df2)

wb2.save(writer)


print ("removed level1 fields")
print ("removed treatment fields")
wb2.close()
wb1.close()
```

---

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this.

Comment: You're not actually using pandas though, at least not in the code you've provided.

Comment: Can you simplify the question a bit?

Comment: My question specifically pertains to the portions of the script like: source__df = pd.read_excel(writer,t)           print(source_df)                   result_df = source_df.drop........     The print(source_df) displays all of the columns as expected, and after the drop, when I try the print(result_df), it also displays the columns as expected, but......if I open the xlsx file in Excel, none of the columns were dropped.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).